# Xamarin.Forms ListView with an AutoSize height

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've read many stackoverflow articles to find out how to set height of the `ListView` so that the `ListView` is exactly as high as is its content.
But none of the many answer solve my needs.

I tried to adapt the basiclist sample in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithlistview/
with this code

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="Hallo"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                        <ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Green" VerticalOptions="Start"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding .}" >
                            <ListView.Footer>
                                <Label />
                            </ListView.Footer>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Hallosdf"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

but no matter what I do, all results in a list thats too high. The green element is the oversized listview. All content below the listview is outside of the viewport.

Thanks a lot.
Uwe

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, its the RowHeight that matters. I have no uneven rows and therefore I can set the RowHeight.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
             VerticalOptions="Fill"
             HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              RowHeight="<some row height>">
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer #7 found in [Xamarin.Forms: ListView inside StackLayout: How to set height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598261/xamarin-forms-listview-inside-stacklayout-how-to-set-height)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi , if question be solved , remember to mark it later when you have time  :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you have nested 2 scroll views with the same direction into each other (`ScrollView` and `ListView`) without one having a fixed height.

**Solution if you want the ListView to shrink to it's contents: Remove the ListView**

There is a `BindableLayout` that can be used with `StackLayout` and other layouts. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <StackLayout >
            <Label Text="Hallo"/>
            <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Green">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}"/> 
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Hallosdf"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

**Solution if you want the ListView to stretch: Remove the Scrollview**

The `Hallosdf` Label will be shown below the `ListView` and only the ListView will scroll. Btw: You don't need to wrap every view in a `StackLayout`. Try to avoid unnecessary layout nesting to gain the best performance. If the `StackLayout` is the only layout within your `AbsoluteLayout`, you can also get rid of the `AbsoluteLayout`.

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <Label Text="Hallo"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" BackgroundColor="Green" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding .}" >
        </ListView>
        <Label Text="Hallosdf"/>
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that the list view cannot be used in such a case?

Comment: I think, there is also a 3rd option, where you listen to several PropertyChanges and calculate the `HeightRequest` of the `ListView` manually each time. For equal height rows, this is relatively easy (`lv.HeightRequest = lv.ItemsCount*rowHeight`) But this problem is not only Xamarin.Forms related. You basically have this in every UI framework (the underlying Android, and iOS controls, too).

Comment: as written by Shimmy in response of that? [Xamarin.Forms ListView size to content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655066/xamarin-forms-listview-size-to-content)

Answer (score 0):

use 
DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView

**xmal**

SfListView Orientation="Horizontal"
QueryItemSize="ListItems_QueryItemSize" ItemsSource="{Binding FavItemList}"

QueryItemSize is use to Set Custom Height of each item

**in Code Behind**

```
private void ListItems_QueryItemSize(object sender,Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.QueryItemSizeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ItemData != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((e.ItemData as FavItemsList).Name))
        {
            e.ItemSize = (e.ItemData as FavItemsList).Name.Count() + 80;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```